Cell reuse problem in collection view in Swift
I have a collection view and in collection view cell I add video to play I want that only one video play at a time and it working perfectly but when I see status of my cpu in xcode I have a crucial problem here
As you know collection view and table view have cell reuse problem so every time I scroll my videos my cpu's status go upto 200+. Which Is not good for health of mobiles
I come from logic that say's I add my play and pause logic to my button action but I don't know how to add the play and pause logic in my button because I have a button in cells xib file so I want a solution for cpu's high load can anyone please help me
I have this code for my collection views cell :-
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class VideoCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var player: AVPlayer?
    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
    var playPauseButton: UIButton!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Setup player layer
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
        playerLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
        contentView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
        // Setup play/pause button
        playPauseButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        playPauseButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        playPauseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playPauseTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        contentView.addSubview(playPauseButton)
        // Layout button
        playPauseButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            playPauseButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            playPauseButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
            playPauseButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            playPauseButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        ])
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer?.frame = contentView.bounds
    }
    func configure(with url: URL) {
        player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        playerLayer?.player = player
    }
    @objc func playPauseTapped() {
        if player?.timeControlStatus == .playing {
            pause()
        } else {
            play()
        }
    }
    func play() {
        player?.play()
        playPauseButton.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)
    }
    func pause() {
        player?.pause()
        playPauseButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
    }
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        player?.pause()
        playerLayer?.player = nil
    }
}

And here the of view controller
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var videoURLs: [URL] = [/* Your video URLs here */]
    var currentlyPlayingIndex: IndexPath?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "VideoCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "VideoCell")
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return videoURLs.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VideoCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoCollectionViewCell
        cell.configure(with: videoURLs[indexPath.item])
        if indexPath == currentlyPlayingIndex {
            cell.play()
        } else {
            cell.pause()
        }
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let currentIndex = currentlyPlayingIndex, let currentCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: currentIndex) as? VideoCollectionViewCell {
            currentCell.pause()
        }
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! VideoCollectionViewCell
        cell.play()
        currentlyPlayingIndex = indexPath
    }
    // Ensuring that the video continues playing even when the cell goes off-screen
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        guard let currentlyPlayingIndex = currentlyPlayingIndex else { return }
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: currentlyPlayingIndex) as? VideoCollectionViewCell {
            // Ensure the cell keeps playing the video if it's the currently playing index
            cell.play()
        }
    }
}


You should not rely on cell players directly. As you have and array of urls use an array of players. You can then give the player to the cell in its configuration. And save the index if the current playing player. The logic is in the controller not in the cell which only display things.

Can you please provide me an a demo or something so that I can understand more because I'm so frustrated about this thing my seniors says that I have to implement the logic of play and pause in button's action and I do that but my cpu temperature is still High upto 200+ or sometime it goes upto 300.

Try releasing the player instance in prepareForReuse: "player = nil". But I pull that logic into the viewController. Make the cell as dumb as possible.
